# Conditionally call a keyed parameter in a macro

Tags: common-lisp

Is it possible to have keywords used\called conditionally? Essentially instead of:

```
(defun test (var)
  (if var
    (some-function :para var)
    (some-function)))
```

I'd want something like this:

```
(defmacro test (var)
  `(some-function (if ,var [add-keyword])))
```

where the function is(for quick easy example purposes):

```
(defun some-function (&key para)
  (cond ((equal para 'yes) "yes")
        ((null para) "no")
        (t "other")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s usually possible to write code in a way to not need to do this (just pass `nil` or the default). But if it really is unavoidable you can use `apply`:

```
(apply #'some-function args... (when var (list :para var)))
```

If you want to pass keyword arguments on, you should use a `&rest` argument with `apply` and `&allow-other-keys`. If you want to pass them on to the next method in CLOS, you should use `call-next-method`. In general it is best to have the set of keyword arguments known at compile time because then the compiler can make things much faster than the unknown case.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I ended up rewriting the function(for other reasons), but the curiosity remained, haha.

Answer (score 3):

One can also detect if a function was called with a keyword parameter:

```
CL-USER 44 > (flet ((example (&key (para nil para-supplied-p))
                      (list para para-supplied-p)))
               (list (example)
                     (example :para nil)
                     (example :para t)))
; para  para-supplied-p
((NIL   NIL)
 (NIL     T)
 (  T     T))
```

Comment: This doesn't allow for not passing a key value into the function though? 

The issue is I am working with SDL, and I wanted to not pass a color parameter if you didn't supply one, but SDL doesn't allow for a nil value on color, thereby forcing you to select a color(it probably defaults to main\screen color, so I rewrote it to mimic a related object's color). 

So while this would work if I developed the SDL library, I didn't thereby I needed my function to be able to select the passing of a key(pre-rewrite). 


Eitherway, thanks for your answer! I learned something new!